# Swift: Create Dictionary with keys based on nested array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, swiftui

#### Goal

I want to sort all items from a `models.json` by categories so that I can display all items divided by their categories using `Dictionary` (see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary))

#### Expected Result (simplified)

Something that looks like that:

```
var rooms = [
  bedroom: [Model3, Model1, Model4],
  bathroom: [Model6, Model1, Model2, Model7],
  livingRoom: [Model1],
]
```

#### What I know

Given a `models.json` I know how to sort by `category` given that `category` is of type `String` and thus only holds one value (see below). The commented code shows my attempt that failed...

`ModelData.swift`

```swift
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = load("models.json")
    
    var categories: [String: [Model]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: models,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }
 
//    How to get all categories within categories.rooms Array?   
//    var rooms: [LivingAreas: [Model]] {
//        Dictionary(
//            grouping: models,
//            by: { ForEach( }
//        )
//    }
}
```

`models.json`

```json
[ 
    {
        "id": "e5a7b533-39c8-4c08-91e9-052a81fbe0df",
        "name": "Cool Chair",
        "category": "chairs",
        "categories": {
            "rooms": ["livingRoom", "bathroom", "bedroom"],
            "furniture": ["Stühle"],
            "style": ["Landhausstil", "Skandinavisch"]
        },
        "file": "chair_swan"
    },
    { ... more items }
]
```

#### What I don't know

Looking at `models.json`, I have a property called `categories` which holds three child properties `rooms`, `furniture` and `style`. Each of them is an Array since each item (a chair, table) can be assigned to multiple categories of that type (e.g. a chair can be used in (`rooms`) the living room and the bedroom. This way, I want that item (as well as all other following items) assigned to all categories in that Array. In the end I would end up with a key / value list, having all categories found in all items as keys and all items (models) that included that key in the according array of that category as values.

Note that I only consider `rooms` for this example. I would replicate the same for `furniture` and `style` later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with a double forEach loop

```
models.forEach { model in 
   model.categories.rooms.forEach { cat in
       rooms[cat, default: []].append(model)
   }
}
```

Create a property for rooms,

```
var rooms: [String: [Model]] = [:]
```

and then add an init to your class

```
init() {
    models = load("models.json")
    models.forEach { model in
        model.categories.rooms.forEach { cat in
            rooms[cat, default: []].append(model)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am using the string values for categories rather than an enum since the enum code isn't included in the question. So either do `cat.rawValue` or perhaps even better change the dictionary to have the enum as key.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Joakim Danielson I figured out a working example:

```swift
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = load("models.json")
    
    var categories: [String: [Model]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: models,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }
    
    var rooms: [String: [Model]] = [:]
    
    init() {
        models = load("models.json")
        models.forEach { model in
            model.categories.rooms.forEach { cat in
                rooms[cat.rawValue, default: []].append(model)
            }
        }
    }
}
```